# Detecting if the app launched from Handoffs or Universal Links

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, handoff, nsuseractivity

Is there a reliable/correct way to determine in the `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` method if the app was opened as a in my app but I need to be able to distinguish the source without having to add anything to the URL.

I've looked through the properties of `NSUserActivity` but nothing there seems to help, since `activityType` returns `NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb` for both Handoffs and Universal Links.

So, is there a correct way to do this or am I supposed to handle both in the same way without knowing the source?

**EDIT:** This is essentially what I'm hoping is possible to accomplish...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if handoff {
        ...
        return true
    } else if universalLink {
        ...
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```